Supernal Man (Adam Kadmon) and other forms
Kabbalah talks about a supernal man (Adam Kadmon), who is in the spiritual realms and somehow parallels the man below.
In that case, is there a supernal cow, supernal oak tree, etc., if everything below has a parallel above?
Or is this concept limited to Adam only?

Do you mean Adam Kadmon?

Yes. That is what I meant.

You are describing various aspects of the Throne of Glory. The throne itself has 4 faces representing the different aspects of animal soul, lion, ox, eagle and man. Adam Kadmon who sits on the throne is the aspect of the G-dly soul in the Human species.

The Supernal Man is unique. Derech Mitzvotecha Heemanat Elokut 11 explains that:

אדם קדמון הוא האור כללי הכולל כל ההשתלשלות כאחד
The Supernal Man is the general Light that includes the entirety of
creation as one.

This even includes animals, as stated later on

קודשא בריך הוא אסתכל באוריתא וברא עלמא אסתכל דוקא שהוא מבחינת עינים דאדם קדמון...שנקרא אור כללי ושם הוא שרש התורה שנקראת משל
הקדמוני...הנה בה ועל ידה האור אין סוף מהוה העולם שעל ידי הכלל נמשך אחר
כך בפרט...וזה סוד דברו חכמים בהוה (שבת ס"ה א) שהדבור של חכמים בח שרצים
על דרך משל...הוא המהוה אותן ושרשן
"Hashem looked into the Torah and created the world" - the term
"looked" refers specifically to the "eyes" of the Supernal Man... which
is called the general light [of all existence]. There is the source of
the Torah, which is called the Primeval Analogy... through which
Hashem's Infinite Light creates the world, through which all the
particulars are drawn down from the general to the specific... and
this is the secret of why "the Chachamim spoke about mundane matters"
[such as animals - see Shabbat 65a], which actually brings them and
their source into being.

As you can see, animals indeed do have their own sources in the higher worlds (for more on this, see Derech Hashem 3), but they are not at all similar to the Supernal Man - they themselves are particulars and the Supernal Man is the general of all existence.
Obviously, this is a very deep and esoteric subject, and apart from answering this very basic question, we can't say more, and what we have understood is extremely basic.

Just one last note, as this is a delicate subject: the Supernal Man is not some sort of idol, or independant being, chas veshalom. As is clarified by the Tzemach Tzedek based on the Zohar:

ולאו דאוריתא ברא עלמא ... אלא שהאין סוף בורא הפרטים על ידי המחשבה
הכללית
It was not the Torah that created the world... but Hashem created the
particulars through this general thought.

